# Get first day and month for last x calendar weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get last 8 week starting from today ( `GETDATE()` )
So the format must be dd/mm for all 8 weeks.
I tried something like this

```
select "start_of_week" = cast(datepart(dd,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)) as CHAR(2))+'/'+cast(datepart(mm,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)) as CHAR(2));
```

and this is good only for the current week, but how to put this in query and return for curr-1,curr-2,...curr-7 weeks. The final result must be table with some amounts for one player and each week in format dd/mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE ( ADate DATETIME )
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME

SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE()

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DateTable WHERE DATEPART( dw, ADate ) = 2) <= 7
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @DateTable
 SELECT @CurrentDate

 SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD( dd, -1, @CurrentDate )

END

SELECT "start_of_week" = cast(datepart(dd,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, ADate), 0)) as CHAR(2))
                        +'/'+cast(datepart(mm,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, ADate), 0)) as CHAR(2)) 
FROM @DateTable 
WHERE DATEPART( dw, ADate ) = 2

DELETE @DateTable
```

**OUTPUT**

```
start_of_week
28/12
21/12
14/12
7 /12
30/11
23/11
16/11
9 /11
```

Comment: Congrats, you got the acceptance... But I must admit, that in my eyes this solution is awful: not needed loop, culture depending, RBAR, ugly date-formatting... However: Sorry and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as easy as this?

```
WITH EightNumbers(Nmbr) AS
(
          SELECT 0 
    UNION SELECT -1
    UNION SELECT -2
    UNION SELECT -3
    UNION SELECT -4
    UNION SELECT -5
    UNION SELECT -6
    UNION SELECT -7
    UNION SELECT -8
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE()+(Nmbr*7),103)
FROM EightNumbers
ORDER BY Nmbr DESC
```

If you need (as the title suggests) the "first day" of the week, you might change the select to:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE()+(Nmbr*7)-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())+@@DATEFIRST,103)
FROM EightNumbers
ORDER BY Nmbr DESC
```

Be aware that the "first day of week" depends on your system's culture. Have a look on `@@DATEFIRST`!

The result:

```
28/12
21/12
14/12
07/12
30/11
23/11
16/11
09/11
02/11
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax :
select "start_of_week" = 
cast(datepart(dd,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - **X**, 0)) as CHAR(2))

```
  select "start_of_week" = 
    cast(datepart(dd,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 0, 0)) as CHAR(2)) ,
"previous_week1" = 
    +'/'+cast(datepart(mm,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)) as CHAR(2)),
"previous_week2" = 
    +'/'+cast(datepart(mm,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 2, 0)) as CHAR(2)),
"previous_week3" = 
    +'/'+cast(datepart(mm,dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 3, 0)) as CHAR(2));
```

and so on.... thank you

Comment: Did you really try this? If you want them "side-by-side" it would be much easier with `convert(varchar(5), getdate()-7 /*set to 14, 21 and so on*/,103)` ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sys.all_objects has at least 8 rows and you want the first day of the week (which you did not specify in your question:

```
select top 8 convert(varchar(5),
        dateadd(WEEK,
                1-1* ROW_NUMBER() over(order by newid()),
                 dateadd(DD,
                            1-datepart(dw,getdate()),
                            getdate())),
        1) as [FirstDayOfWeek]
  from sys.all_objects
```

The convert just gives the month/day. The row number is used to give the numbers 1-8. I multiplied the row number by -1 and added 1 to get the numbers 0,-1,-2,...-7 and date added those (by day) to the first day of this week. I found the first day of this week by taking getdate and date adding the negative version of the day of the week + 1.